# Can't run Rocket.Chat server on Ubuntu without Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, rocket.chat

I've been following this tutorial to install Rocket.Chat on Ubuntu:

https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/wiki/Deploy-Rocket.Chat-without-docker

Everything looks good until I try to run the server with `node main.js`:

`Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/gregoire/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:213:1)`

`localhost` could also be `127.0.0.1` or my IP address, it doesn't change anything. Sounds like an error coming from `MongoDB`.

So I tried to run with `sudo` and the error I'm getting is different:

`Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment`

I follow the tutorial, this variable has been set using `export`:

`export ROOT_URL=http://localhost/
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/rocketchat
export PORT=80`

**EDIT:**

I needed to start `mongod` to then run the `main.js`. But I also got an error:

```
mongodb failed to connect to 127.0.0.1
```

I made some research and found that I had a missing folder. I used this command to create it and then started `mongod`:

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

It worked after that, but it's not implied in the tutorial. I'm currently repeating the setup on a server and I'm having the same problem: `/data/db` is missing.

Comment: Did you have to run the commands from "Install Dependencies"? I thought that when you installed mongoDB, it would automatically create /data/db for you... Is it not the case? What's your OS version?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10. I installed mongoDB using the commands given in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

> Disclaimer: I work for Rocket.Chat.

Are you sure mongodb is running? Can you type `mongo` and see if you can get into a mongoDB shell? If it's running, can you please confirm it's running on port 27017?

You can also go to https://demo.rocket.chat and join #support channel or #dev, where you'll find quite a few developers willing to help you out.

Comment: I can't run `mongo`. I was able to make it work by creating a missing folder: `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`. I'm not sure if this is a clean solution though.

Comment: This doesn't seem right at all! You can't run `mongo` because you are not allowed to, or because it is not running on your system? It's impossible to use Rocket.Chat without MongoDB, so I'm guessing it's the first option.

Comment: We have a new docs for installing on Ubuntu, without Docker. Please check out at: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Docs/blob/master/3.%20Installation/4.%20Manual%20Installation/Ubuntu/README.md